# ubuntu time glitch

Tags: time

Running **20.04lts on gateway e-475m laptop**, dual boot with *win7*, and 'use internet to set clock' is **OFF** for both OS's (reason will become obvious...), and my bios clock is set for local time.

For *win7* I have time zone set to eastern and all is 'normal', but if ubuntu is set for eastern, it takes that time, and sets ubuntu clock ***4 hours ahead*** on boot (ie 7am becomes 11am) for some reason (again, even though ubuntu is set for eastern time zone), and then if I reset it in ubuntu to local time, it then changes the bios clock so *win7* gets messed up when I dual boot back to *win7*.

My work around is to tell ubuntu it is at UTC, not eastern, and it leaves the darn bios clock as it is... but why this 'glitch'?!? Is there a real 'fix'...

ANSWER: run "sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1" and all is fine! (just why all the ruckus?)

Comment: You should be able to tell Win that the HW clock is set to UTC. I did that years ago when I was still running win on one machine. Linux uses that in any case.

Comment: This is not a glitch. All unix records time as the number of seconds which have passed since 1 January 1970, UTC. This is what is meant by the "Unix Epoch Time". You'll note that this standard has existed longer than Windows. Tell Windows that your hardware clock is set to UTC. This is the correct fix.

Comment: This is not a new issue.  You are better off adhering to the duplicate thread of "Clock time is off on dual boot" - the issue is not a new one though.  I suggest `chronyd` to set up NTP on your system if you need automated time sync, the inbuild `timesyncd` is... eh.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to set correct timezones on both systems and then install reliable [NTP client from Meinberg](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm#ntp_stable) inside the Windows.

Then reboot to Ubuntu and enjoy. It will set its time from NTP on start.

This method does not require any additional steps. Having correct precise network time on machines is essential for all devices.

Comment: It'd be easier to just configure Ubuntu to not use UTC for the system clock... which is the 'standard' approach for dualboots...

Comment: OK, so all that was needed was to run: "sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1"

That's all folks! (just ignore all the rest...)